# How do I make sure user input is bigger than previous user input?

Tags: c

I need to have the user input a positive number and then another positive number.
The second number *2 must be bigger than the first.
Here is what I have but it does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double radius; //radius of circle//
    double side_a; //side a of rectangle that will be asked//
    double num_pol; //number of sides to polygon//
    double side_b; //side a of rectangle that will be calculated//
    double S_circ; //surface of cercle//
    double S_rect; //surface of rectangle//
    double S_pol; //surface of polygon//
    double P=3.1416; //the number pi//    
    double diameter; // the diameter pf the circle//
    do
    {
        printf_s("enter a value for a:");
        scanf_s("%lf", &side_a);
    } while (side_a < 0);
    do
    {
    printf_s("enter a value for r:");
    scanf_s("%lf", &radius);
    diameter=radius*2;
    } while (radius < 0 && diameter < side_a);
}
```

Comment: can you show the i/o and errors?

Comment: there is no output only input. there are no errors. user must enter pos num for ex: 90 and then another pos num for ex 55. if he enters a number smaller than 90/2 the program must ask fo a number again.

Comment: okk editing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`radius < 0 && diameter < side_a` this is wrong.

You need an OR here: `radius < 0 || diameter < side_a`

You need to exit the loop when `radius>0 && diameter>sid_a`

Loop exits on `false` condition.

Using **de Morgan**: `!(a&&b) = a||b`